# Adding date and time to an image captured via UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I would like to add the date and time to an image taken using the `UIImagePickerController`.

I have an app that uses the controller to take a photo, and while I know the date is stored in the metadata, I wondered if it can be easily incorporated into the image (much like you can set a digital camera to) like the example shown below:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to display the date on the image or do you want to send the image to other with date added to it..

Comment: As I wrote I want to "incorporated into the jpg image" i.e. so it becomes part of the image. Is it that bad a question?

Answer (score 0):

Note, this will only work when the ImageIO framework is imported and included. Another condition is:

> [UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata] is valid only when using an image picker whose source type is set to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera, and applies only to still images.

This is the way we retrieve the date from the image. If you were allowing images to be selected via the Photo Album, then this solution will not work. For that you'd need to leverage `ALAsset`. If you're purely using the camera (and running on iOS7), this solution should work.

```
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

// Ensure you've set yourself as the UIImagePickerController delegate to ensure this method is called
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage* image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    image = [self imageWithRenderedDateMetadata:info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata]
                                        onImage:image];
}

- (UIImage*)imageWithRenderedDateMetadata:(NSDictionary*)metadata onImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    if (!image || !metadata) { return nil; }

    // Get Date String
    // Note: You can format the date string here into a more readable format if you want
    // Here, I'll just use the YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS format given
    NSDictionary *tiffMetadata = metadata[(__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary];
    NSString* dateString = tiffMetaData[(__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyTIFFDateTime];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

    // Draw the image into the context
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];

    // Position the date in the bottom right
    NSDictionary* attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName :[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:30],
                                 NSStrokeColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor],
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor yellowColor],
                                 NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : @-2.0};

    const CGFloat dateWidth = [dateString sizeWithAttributes:attributes].width;
    const CGFloat dateHeight = [dateString sizeWithAttributes:attributes].height;
    const CGFloat datePadding = 25;

    [dateString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(image.size.width - dateWidth - datePadding, image.size.height - dateHeight - datePadding)
             withAttributes:attributes];

    // Get the final image
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

You now have a UIImage with the date incorporated within it; the end result looks something like this:

[image: End result of timestamp rendered onto the image]